# Undefinded method in view for instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller like this:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tasks = Task.where(done: false)
  end
end
```

and my view file in

> views/tasks/index.html.erb

I have this code:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <li class="item"><%= task.content %></li>
<% end %>
```

And when I go to the tasks/index in the browser I get an error:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

I've thought the problem is the empty Task table so I added some tasks by rails console.
Log from rails console:

```
2.1.2 :002 > Task.where(done: false)
  Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."done" = 'f'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Task id: 1, content: "go to home", done: false, created_at: "2014-10-03 19:53:17", updated_at: "2014-10-03 19:53:17">, #<Task id: 2, content: "go to bed", done: false, created_at: "2014-10-03 19:53:27", updated_at: "2014-10-03 19:53:27">]>
```

So you can see there are some records.

So where did I make a mistake?

Comment: And the `undefined method` error is on the line that iterates over `@tasks`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Exactly line `<% @tasks.each do |task| %>`.

Comment: check full error stack. Maybe your view has another iteration. and `nil.each` is called there

Comment: Try to add a raise on the last line of index method and check if it stops there. raise @tasks.inspect